# Weird tcpclient https post response

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, response, tcpclient

I have a weird problem trying to get full response from a web page using `TcpClient` which I send a POST to. Here the code:

```
byte[] RecvBufferxxxx = new byte[4096];

var returnData = "";
var uri = new Uri(string.Format(core.serverAuth, "app_data"));
var head = new WebHeaderCollection();
head[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = uri.Host;
head[HttpRequestHeader.Connection] = "keep-alive";
head[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "deflate";

using (var client = new TcpClient(uri.Host, 443))
{
    client.SendTimeout = 10000;
    client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
    using (SslStream s = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, 
        IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler, null))
    {
        s.AuthenticateAsClient(uri.Host, null, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

        var hhd = "POST " + uri.PathAndQuery + " HTTP/1.0\r\n" + head;

        var bts = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hhd);
        s.Write(bts, 0, bts.Length);
        s.Flush();
        s.ReadByte();

        var n = s.Read(RecvBufferxxxx, 0, RecvBufferxxxx.Length);
        // var tmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RecvBufferxxxx, 0, n);
        // ANOTHER CALL SAMPLE   
        // n = s.Read(RecvBufferxxxx, 0, RecvBufferxxxx.Length);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(RecvBufferxxxx, 0, n))
        {
            ms.ReadByte();
            ms.ReadByte();
            using (DeflateStream df = new DeflateStream(ms, 
                CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(df))
                {
                    returnData = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, but it gets only the response headers, I need to make another call to get the response body and i don't know why.

The response is from my server and is very short.

Before I was using only `Socket` and it was getting all in one call, but now i have rewritten it as in code adding SSL and deflate.

I have check the same link in firefox with firebug and there is only one get and full response.

I have double check it with wireshark and firebug, using firebug and this code wireshark listing looks quite the same.

I can make the second read with this code and then i get the response body, but then i see in wireshark that there was another ssl connection made and i don't want this, i want just as firefox does this.

Another reason is i just want to know why this is happing an dhow to fix these, can someone help me ?

Comment: Why aren't you using the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx) class?  Or if you require more detailed control over the request, the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class?  Both handle the deflation of compressed streams, SSL, and POST requests.

Comment: This is not my question, use webclient or httpwebrequest is not an answer. Read my problem again.

Comment: @svick: Homework, perhaps?  If so, the `homework` tag should be applied to it.

Comment: @Programista: I did read your question, there's no need to remind me to re-read it (I even edited it to make it *better*).  The comment *is* an answer, it's just not the answer you want (which leads me to believe this is homework, and should have the [tag:homework] tag applied to it)

Comment: Of course i don't want this answer, i'm trying to make it with tcpclient, don't force me to change that if you just don't know the answer, it is fast and the code executes when form starts, that is the reason. IT IS NOT HOMEWORK. But even if it was,, have you tested it at least ?, i have.
If you don't know the answer probably you have never use tcpclient with ssl, but this is my problem.
"Use webclient/webrequest" is not an answer, i see this every time someone asks tcpclient, "use something else" coz this is hard or the former are easier. I will try reflector then, to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution, but not the problem origin, just use `ReadByte` in loop, don't know why `Read` has problems, using reflector i was able to find that it could be a problem with `SslStream` internal buffering, but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

[`Stream.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) may not give you the whole buffer, it is allowed to return less. If you want to read the whole stream, you have to call it in a loop until it returns 0.

Comment: There is plenty of room in the buffer, response is very short <250 letters.

Thing is it returns first response headers, then response body, besides firefox is doing this in one call, if i made second read i will have second ssl transaction and this is not the desired effect. My code is close to low level to if ff could do this and any other browser then why this code can't.

And i surprised this is happening.

Comment: It doesn't matter that there is enough room in the buffer. You just can't assume that `Read()` will give you everything in one go. One reason for this is that the response might be in more than one packet and you might want to start processing before the last one arrives. I don't know much about SSL, but are you sure another `Read()` will create another transaction?

Comment: "response might be in more than one packet" , but when i use only socket or httpwebrequest it is in one call so...?

Comment: No idea, maybe you changed something else too, that makes the difference.

Comment: Nope, you have the code, just test it, it can be any https data source.

Comment: I just did. Yeah, the first `Read()` does return only the HTTP header, but the second `Read()` doesn't send or receive any data.